# Share via Ajax link ima my aplication stream publish

Tags: facebook-graph-api

When my application creates a new post, it will automatically show up under the links "like" and comment, but does not appear to" share ". Would like to create an action for sharing with ajax, but do not know how. Does anyone know how to create this link ?

http://www.facebook.com/ajax/share_dialog.php?s=99&appid=&p[]=

how do I get information in my application to concatenate to build this link?

My Code:

$attachment = array(

```
'access_token'=> $ACCESS_TOKEN,
'name'=> $TITLE,
'message'=> '',
'description'=> $DESCRIPTION,
'caption'=>'',
'picture'=>'',
'link'=>  $LINK,
'actions'=> array( array(
                           'name' => 'SHARE', 
                           'link' => "http://www.facebook.com/ajax/share_dialog.php?appid=$APP_ID")
                   ));
```

See image: No link to share the post.

[image]

thanks!

Comment: I read that facebook only creates the link "share" if the content of the post has an external link or a picture / video, but even if my post contains this link, it does not generate the link "share". Any idea ????

Answer (score 2):

The following notes answers your question.

- The destination page of an FB share must contain the right title, img and open graph tags as desired by your "share" or "post". Facebook uses this to determine what to show in the post.
- If your page is controlled by you, then of course, you can control this experience.
- If your page is inside facebook (specially a tab application), then you can't control this since your destination would be a "https://www.facebook.com/page/?sk=app_xxx" link and that can't be controlled by you.

So, what we did is to create an intermediary page (say http://redirect.com/abcde) with the above properties and use that as the destination to the "share" links. The intermediary page then does nothing except to the forward the user to the right tab application. So, you manage to control the exact experience.

Comment: Did this solve your problem? Please accept the answer if it does.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to hack together a workaround for the AJAX Share popup, however you can very easily publish a post with an action link to sharer.php:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?message=Testing&actions=[{"name":"Share","link":"https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://example.com&t=Share Title"}]&method=post&access_token=TOKEN
```

This is a very simplified way to add an action link to a published story. You could also use one of the newer, non-deprecated [Dialogs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/) that can be linked to via hyperlink.

You can also add your voice to [this bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/164888633588257) which is requesting the standard Share link be added in for app published stories.

Answer (score 0):

if you are attaching links then change the feed type `me/links` instead of `me/feed`. And this will show share in actions